# session | shopping cart | MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

As in shopping cart application, we use session to store the user selected items and show them from the cart.

Now in  MVC, as there is no concept of session, and every action is going to be new controller call and will generate the view accordingly. So how can i store the list of the items selected in web server itself ( i can  do it by saving in DB and later retrieving it ). but wanted to know if there is any other way.

Comment: There is the concept of session in MVC too.. do some google.

Comment: ASP MVC4 does support the Session object. You can use it like you would in Webforms: `Session["name"] = value;` and retrieve it by: `var x = Session["name"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perfectly use Session in ASP.Net MVC as you do in Webforms:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["NAME"] = value;
value = HttpContext.Current.Session["NAME"];
```